# Highscore table - How to highest score per user?

Tags: mysql

Yep there are many similar questions, but I really couldn't solve my problem. Unfortunately I don't have enough knowladge to understand that similar question's answers to solve mine ^^.

I have id, name, score , ip variables. I don't care about id or ip variables..

My query like this;

`$query = "SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY score + 0  DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($query);`

This gives higscore table but, there are same user's different scores. I want to show highest score per user.

I don't even know why there is + 0 on my code. And why if I delete it table doesn't show as desc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will give you the name of each player and his best score :

```
SELECT name, MAX(score) FROM highscores GROUP BY name ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I had already tried this before, unfortunately it gives me an Undefined offset error. I guess I should create a query inside of query with inline or smth like that to first define that variables.

Comment: @user1101028, what variables?

Comment: Are you sure your score column is a numeric type? You shouldn't have to use `+ 0`.

Comment: Oh you are right. I guess thats why. But I don't know how to set it as numeric. I just used this $score = $_POST['score'];
$query = "INSERT INTO highscores(name, score, ip) VALUES('$name', '$score', '$ip')";

Comment: @ Mike Daniels

I mean it points my echo $row[2]; line with that error.(score row) I guess that row doesn't have values on that point.

Comment: Column types are defined when you create a table (although you can change them later, here with something like `ALTER TABLE highscores MODIFY score INT NOT NULL`). I recommend you to read some MySQL tutorials, this is very basic stuff.

Comment: So you mean "SELECT name, MAX(score) FROM highscores GROUP BY name ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC LIMIT 10" this should work but it doesn't work beceause my score variable's type automaticaly defined unnumerical ? And I have to typecast it to numerical like "$newint = (int) $var1;" ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with php. MySQL don't know that you are storing only numbers in your column if you don't set it to a numeric type. That's why the MAX function fails and you get an error.

Comment: Yep sorry about that. I looked from phpmyadmin, and changed column type from there to int.. Then I tested it with my regular code without +0 , and It worked perfect. Then I tried with SELECT name, MAX(score) FROM highscores GROUP BY name ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC LIMIT 10 but It gives same error " [1] Nick=24 Score=
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in" By the way nick should be name, and that 24 should be on score side.

Comment: Solved. Thank you very much for your help.. For some reason, I should have add id and ip variables to select too. $query = "SELECT id, name, MAX(score), ip FROM highscores GROUP BY name ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC";

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM highscores ORDER BY ABS(score) DESC LIMIT 10";
```

That should allow you to run the query without the zero.

As for removing duplicate user scores from the list, either only record each user's best score or do some further processing to remove them from the list. It would be quite simple to loop through the results and only pick each user's highest scores.

Comment: Yep, with ABS I can run query without zero. Still I don't know why others don't use abs or zero, but I should ^^.

Yeah I guess I have to create one more query to pick best score for same users. But I don't know how to do it yet.